# Does not enter controller from @ url.action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, it does not return anything to me and it does not enter my controller. Someone knows why

```
<div class="col-xs-12 input-group input-group-sm">
    <span  style="padding: 2px 20px 0px 50px;"><strong>Ingrese Código de la Imagen:</strong></span>
    <div class="form-validator" style="padding: 2px 10px 0px 350px;">
        <div style="float: left;">
            <img id="CaptchaImg" src="@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage", "Account", new { random = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() })" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <img alt="" src="" class="invoice img_refresh" id="refresh" onclick="RecargaCaptcha('@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage", "Account")');" />
        </div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordNuevo, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "width:500px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public CaptchaImageResult ShowCaptchaImage(string random)
{
    return new CaptchaImageResult();
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML view look like? With so many strings in strings, most likely that entire tag is treated as a string.

Comment: what happens instead? Is there an error? Check your browser's developer tools to see what happened to the request. I'm going to speculate that it has something to do with authorisation

Comment: what do you recommmend me to do?

Comment: I recommend you to check for errors, like I just said. And post the generated HTML, as Panagiotis said. Learn to debug your application in more detail.

Comment: in the console of my browser does not bring me any errors

Comment: and in the network tab, when it tries to load the image from that URL, what status code do you get?

Comment: I do not get any errors either

Comment: That's not what I asked. What status code do you get for that URL? And have you checked that the generated HTML (which is produced by the Razor code you've shown) is correct and as expected including the correct URL?

Comment: [link]@using (Html.BeginForm("ActualizaPass", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) .........

Comment: Sorry I don't see the relevance of that to what I asked you? It just looks like more Razor code, so not HTML, not a status code report. Also if you have extra info like that please edit it into your question. Code in comments is not very easy to read. Thankyou.